# More components or just html in one page angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to understand which is the better approach for performance. I have a page where my header, body and footer sections are there. Header and footer sections are just plain htmls. There are 2 approaches for this like in app.component.html i can include 3 components, creating components helps me in modularizing and re-usability.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-body></app-body>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Other way is just write whole of the html in app-component.html.

Which is the better approach seeing that header and footer has just htmls. Does making those as components degrade the performance?

Comment: Adding two components won't have any significant impact on performance (if any). If it did, Angular would be unusable. Stop worrying about performance, and think about readability, maintainability, and the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: Do understand, but its just html snippet. Component may be an overload for just html inclusion right? yeah 2 component will not downgrade perfromance, say in a page i have 5-6 different sections, in which few sections have just html and others interactive components. Even then those html sections should be made to components just for readability purpose?

Comment: Do what you feel is the best, and start optimizing if you have a performance problem, and if you proved the performance problem comes from that choice.

Comment: In this case I think the benefit of dividing it would it modularity for future implementations. If it is one page and it will not change in the future you can use only one html. Modularity is for handling complex apps and performance too.

Answer (score 0):

I think plain HTML is always going to be faster than any framework in terms of rendering ... just because Angular or React are cool doesn't mean you need to add useless stuff like nested components that do nothing (ex thumbnails for 2-3 fields )